# QuerySelector Id Target when Matches Value in Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting, object

I cannot figure out how to correctly target and display an HTML id tag when a corresponding matching JS object, contained within an array, has a "live" value of true.

I want a JS loop to display a link in schedule module only if that link id matches the "scheduleId" of an object and when that object's "live" value is true. How would I target and display this link?

See my HTML here:

```
<div class="test-schedule">
   <h2>Schedule</h2>
   <div><span>School of Ed</span><a class="link-class" id="ed">School of Ed link</a></div>
   <div><span>School of Humanities</span><a class="link-class" id="hss">School of Humanities link</a></div>
   <div><span>School of Science</span><a class="link-class" id="sci">School of Science link</a></div>
   <div><span>School of Nursing</span><a class="link-class" id="nursing">School of Nursing link</a></div>
</div>


<style>
.link-class{display:none}
</style>
```

JS here:

```
const eventList = [

  {
    scheduleId: 'ed',
    live: 'true',
  },
  {
    scheduleId: 'hss',
    live: 'false',
  },
  {
    scheduleId: 'sci',
    live: 'false',
  },
  {
    scheduleId: 'nursing',
    live: 'false',
  },
];
```

Codepen link:
https://codepen.io/lvl12sealclubber/pen/PoWbJZQ?editors=1011

Comment: i dont understant your problem..its not clear

Comment: Thanks @Frenchy, I've revised my post to help clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want all the links to be hidden and only display some based on a JS value? Could you just do:

```css
.link-class {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```js
for (let event of eventList) {
    if (event.live) {
        document.getElementById(event.scheduleId).style.visibility="visible" 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you want to show the link of that event based on if the event is live on the events object, you can try something simple like creating a class that will show the element like this

```js
const eventList = [
  {
    scheduleId: "ed",
    live: "true",
  },
  {
    scheduleId: "hss",
    live: "false",
  },
  {
    scheduleId: "sci",
    live: "true",
  },
  {
    scheduleId: "nursing",
    live: "false",
  },
];

const checkLinks = () => {
  for (let event of eventList) {
    if (event.live === "true") {
      document.querySelector("#" + event.scheduleId).classList.add("show-link");
      console.log(event.scheduleId);
    }
  }
};

checkLinks();
```

```css
.link-class {
  display: none;
}

.show-link {
  display: inline-block;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
    <div class="test-schedule">
      <h2>Schedule</h2>
      <div>
        <span>School of Ed </span
        ><a class="link-class" id="ed">School of Ed link</a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span>School of Humanities </span
        ><a class="link-class" id="hss">School of Humanities link</a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span>School of Science </span
        ><a class="link-class" id="sci">School of Science link</a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span>School of Nursing </span
        ><a class="link-class" id="nursing">School of Nursing link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I’d update data type for ‘live’ property to a boolean instead of a string.

In a real world, this will be data driven and you wouldn’t have to compare dates but just check the ‘live’ property if it’s true or not.

If I understand correctly, when a user lands on this page, you calculate the current date/time and show which event is live. If this is the case, you can just compare current date/time and show link for the one that is live. There is no need to update `event.live`. In fact, you shouldn't update your data through JS.

Also, instead of updating style for banner through JS, just maintain a placeholder on the top and control styles through CSS. I didn’t see a value to do it through JS.

Answer (score 0):

You could `filter` out the unwanted array elements and then use a simple `forEach` to display. Something like this:

```js
const eventList = [{
  scheduleId: 'ed',
  live: 'true',
}, {
  scheduleId: 'hss',
  live: 'false',
}, {
  scheduleId: 'sci',
  live: 'false',
}, {
  scheduleId: 'nursing',
  live: 'true',
}];

const scheduleEl = document.querySelector("#schedule")
eventList
  .filter(event => event.live === 'true')
  .forEach(event => {
    scheduleEl.innerHTML += `<p>- ${event.scheduleId}</p>`;
  });
```

```html
<p>Live event schedule:</p>
<div id="schedule">
</div>
```